# SSL Domain Error in IPhone- https connection

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ssl, https

I am using CFNetwork to connect to a https webservice , whose server is a Verisign certified. I get the appropriate response from the server  some times. But the rest of the time I am getting two kind of errors.
 1."**Operation could not be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9807.)**
 2.**"Operation could not be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -4.)"**

I am using SDK 3.0 and tested it in 3.1 also. I don't get a consistent result. Please some one help me to solve the issue.

Regards,
Krishnan

Comment: Got same 9807 error as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Michael,

Just give full details about your problem. I had this problem only in iPhone Simulator and when I finally tested it in the device, there was no problem at all and it went well.

Regards,
krishnan.

Comment: The problem only occurred in the simulator and not in the Device. So if some one comes across this problem, please check in your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only occurred in the simulator and not in the Device. So if some one comes across this problem, please check in your device and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the date and time on your device or simulator. A wrong time/date will prevent you from connecting.